# accessing list elements in java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I created a linkedlist object as follows

```
 importBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(importcsvFile));
              while ((line = importBuffer.readLine()) != null) {

                  // use comma as separator
                  String[] importedFile = line.split(cvsSplitBy); //cap,comune,provincia,stato

                  System.out.println("Codice Azienda " + importedFile[0] + " , Codice Cliente=" + importedFile[1] + " , Regione Sociale=" + importedFile[2] + " , Indrizzo=" + importedFile[3] + " , comune=" + importedFile[4] + " , provincia=" + importedFile[5] + " , stato=" + importedFile[6] +"]");
                  counter++;
                  PublicDefinition.importList.add(importBuffer.toString());

                  List customers = select.select(importedFile[0],importedFile[1], importedFile[3]);

                  if(!customers.isEmpty())
                  {

                 System.out.println("selected Customer  : " + customers.size());   
                 buffureList = customers;
                 Object a=List.class.cast(customers);

                 PublicDefinition.testingList.add(buffureList.toString());

                 System.out.println("selected Customer  : " + PublicDefinition.importList.get(0));
                 System.out.println("selected Customer  : " + PublicDefinition.testingList.getFirst());

                 updateCustomer =  customers;
                 if(customers.get(0)==importedFile[0])
                     System.out.println("Matched Codice Azienda");
                 select.updateTable(importedFile[1], importedFile[3], "10.34", "11.40"); //String CodiceCliente, String indrizzo, String latitude, String longitute         
                  }
              }
```

when I try to access the elements for the linkedlist using

```
System.out.println("selected Customer  : " + PublicDefinition.importList.get(0));
```

I got the output:

```
selected Customer  : java.io.BufferedReader@420dc55b
```

I think this is the memory reference, but I want to retrieve the value of the linkedlist

my select function is:

```
public List<Customer> select(String codiceAzienda, String codiceCliente, String indrizzo) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CodiceAzienda= ?",
                new Object[] { codiceAzienda},
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"),
                         rs.getString("CodiceAzienda"), rs.getString("Indrizzo"), rs.getString("codice_cliente"), rs.getString("Indrizzo")));
    }
```

Comment: You are are getting what you added.

Comment: Please post your full functional code.

Comment: I just re posted it.

Comment: @user2229430 would you mind marking any of the suggested answers as answer please

Answer (score 3):

You added the `toString()` value of the importBuffer **object**, not the actual contents. The default `toString()` implementation (which every object inherits from... `Object`) returns `ClassName@HashCode`. So your output isn't wrong, but your input is.

See [Object.toString() in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and perform:
    **PublicDefinition.importList.add(importBuffer.readLine());** 
Instead of : 
    **PublicDefinition.importList.add(importBuffer.toString());**

Since you are trying to output the contents of the buffered reader instead of the ClassName@Hashcode contents.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`PublicDefinition.importList.add(importBuffer.toString());`

with

`PublicDefinition.importList.add(importedFile);`

You are accidentally adding the string representation of `BufferReader` object, not the list of import files which sounds like your intention.